# How to enable: Switch back to running GUI from TTY in 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gui, tty

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and an important feature is missing: the option to switch between GUI and TTY.

From the GUI I can switch to one of 4 TTY, by Ctrl-Alt-F3 to Ctrl-Alt-F6. I can login in the tty, do whatever I wish. When I Press Alt-F1, I get to the login-screen, not back to running GUI session.

How can I customize 20.04 LTS in this way?

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F2 should take you back to GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to return to the graphical desktop. On TTY1, the GDM login manager is running, on TTY2 the desktop.

Comment: Why Alt+F2 instead of Ctrl+Alt+F2?

Comment: @ValerioBozz  Use Ctrl+Alt+F2 if you prefer and don't mind the extra keypress. Within a virtual console, Alt+arrow also will let you move back and forth between consoles.